# Export Hidden columns in js ag-grid to excel

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid. One column in that ag-grid is hidden. But I want to have that column exported to excel. I am using the default context menu (Right click to export it).  I tried to configure allColumn: true but it did not work. The export is in the context menu, how can I configure it

Answer (score 0):

The property **allColumns** on the **ExcelExportParams** should definitely work. Are you sure you are passing it correctly?

```
gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel({
  allColumns: true
})
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-api/#reference-ExcelExportParams-allColumns